# Are MAUI and SQL Server Compatible?

Tags: sql-server, maui

I have a MAUI app, and I have just decided to switch databases from Google's Firestore to Microsofts SQL Server and am having issues with compatabilty.

I have included the using `System.Data.SqlClient;` using statment and then attempt to use SqlConnection. But I get the error that:

> The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0.

To preface in my .csproj it shows my SDK and framework to be:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

I also have installed the `System.Data.SqlClient` package already.

I'm not sure if my packets are all messed up or not but some of the things I have looked at and tried are packages for my solution.

When searching my installed packages (in NuGet - solution) the only SDK I have installed is `Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK`.
To me it seems like the `Microsoft.Maui.Sdk` should be installed?

(However my project was working fine without it when using Firestore)

When trying to install the Maui SDK I get the error that:

> Error NU1213 The package Microsoft.Maui.Sdk 8.0.6 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project.

I am stuck and just wondering if anyone can identify the next steps to take to allow my app to work with SQL Server?

Comment: Given the ARM64-isms of Android, iOS, and Mac Catalyst have you tried to reference `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of the legacy `System.Data.SqlClient`? Although, really, why haven't you abstracted the database away behind a (RESTful, etc.) web API?

Comment: Why is your SqlClient being added directly to your MAUI project :|

Comment: Agree with above speakers, you shouldn't connect to sql server directly from mobile apps, it's both insecure and probably bad performant

Comment: I am still somewhat new to code, and database work as well, along with the fact this is a practice app, but I will look into using a web API, however, I am on a small scale, and even if it is not the most safe or efficient should still be able to use the SqlConnection related libraries, so I am unsure where I have been unable to connect. (When I try and use (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) .Data is not recognized.